# how to extract from a table and insert into another table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have 2 tables. TABLE A,table B . I need to extract  data lets say code and name from table A and insert into table B. while insering it should take the next code. At the same table A is also updated.  Am not using stored procedure for this. Pls help me to achieve this 
for eg:

**Table A**

```
code  name

1   aaa

2   bbb
```

**Table B**

```
code name

1   ccc 

2   ddd
```

result should be like this:

**table B**

```
code name

1 ccc
2 ddd
3 aaa
4 bbb
```

**TABLE A**

```
3 aaa

4 bbb
```

any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for

```
Insert Into TableB(Code,Name)
Select Code,Name from TableA
```

Comment: i need to update the code with next number. i have taken max( code ) into a variable. dont know how to apply this. same time i need to change in table A also.

Comment: I used like this. 
insert into TABLE B(code,name) select  " & code & ",name  from tableA.
But am not able to increment the code. code is the variable which contains max(code)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
INSERT INTO TableB(Code,Name)
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Code) + (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM TableB), name FROM TableA

UPDATE TableA SET TableA.Code = TableB.Code FROM TableA
INNER JOIN TableB ON TableA.Name = TableB.Name
```